# Why can not get value from application in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, javabeans

`I have a problem
I trying get value from applycation.properties to my class.
I have configured in many other classes this way and it is still valid until...
This is my class that i want get value from PATH.STORAGE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTEeM.png)

private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(FilesStorageServiceImpl.class);

```
@Value("${PATH.STORAGE}")
String storage ;

private final Path root = Paths.get(storage);
```

And this is my app.properties
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2cUQ.png)

PATH.STORAGE=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\storage

Thanks everyone.

I try change value of PATH.STORAGE=A or PATH.STORAGE=B ...
I try add config in .properties:
spring.resources.static-locations=file:///${PATH.STORAGE}`

Comment: Does the field have a set method？

Comment: does field `root` really need to be `final`? Try to remove `final` keyword or try to get  `Paths.get(storage)` inside your method